# Changing file permission for NTFS format

Tags: filesystem, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to 'chmod' on an NTFS ( or FAT32 ) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

I am trying to change the file/directory permission. But it is not changing either through using command line or GUI.

This fil/dir is present in one of the partition in external harddisk which is in NTFS file format. Dees that make any difference?

Any help how could I modify the permissions in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NTFS doesn't support file permissions like Linux partitions.

See this for a workaround: [Any way of maintaining permissions when using NTFS mounted drive in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86959/any-way-of-maintaining-permissions-when-using-ntfs-mounted-drive-in-ubuntu)