# How come I cannot make this file executable (chmod permissions)?

Tags: permissions, java, android, eclipse

I downloaded Android Development Tool for linux (ADT) and placed it in home directory. After unzipping the files, when I double click the "eclipse" executable file; the eclipse works perfectly fine.

But If I unzip the ADT in a different directory, in my case directory E: (is shown when I boot in windows 7) There double clicking the same "eclipse" executable file does not run eclipse. It shows error message:

> Could not display
>   `/media/Software/00.AndroidLinux/ADT/eclipse/eclipse`. There is no
>   application installed for executable files. Do you want to search for
>   an application to open this file?

If I press yes in the Dialog, it finds "Pypar2" which is not my solution.

I found that the "eclipse" file permission is following

```
-rw------- 1 tanvir tanvir 63050 Feb  4 19:05 eclipse
```

I tried to change the permission by "chmod +x eclipse" , but no use. This command does not change the file permission at all in this case.

what should I do?

Relevant output of `cat /proc/mounts`:

```
/dev/sda6 /media/Software fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Please not that I'm new to Ubuntu and still learning day by day.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What kind of filesystem are you using on `/media/Software`? (Please include the output of `cat /proc/mounts` in your question.) I guess this is a non-Linux filesystem which cannot hold file permission metadata, e.g. FAT32 and NTFS cannot.

Comment: /media/Software is NTFS file system.

Comment: Is `/media/Software` loaded automatically at boot, or is it a manually-mounted partition?

Comment: [/media/Software] is manually-mounted partition @ThomasW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following worked for me:

First, save the old copy of `/etc/fstab` to say `$HOME/fstab.old`

Now run

```
$mount
```

to get the device type (eg, `/dev/sda3`), look for where the drive is mounted,

**Example**:

```
/dev/sda3 on /some/path type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

(**NOTE**: In your case the device type and the directory where it's mounted will be different).

Find the `UUID` of the disk by running:

```
$blkid
```

On my system this returned:

```
/dev/sda3: UUID="90FEDFC7FEDFA3AE" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Copy/paste the following entry in your `/etc/fstab` file:  (run `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` to edit)

```
UUID=90FEDFC7FEDFA3AE /media/Software ntfs rw,noauto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

(**NOTE**: **WRITE THE UUID OF YOUR DISK**. Also provide any path that is convinient to you).

Restart your computer.
Now you should be able to execute any file.

Comment: There's no need to reboot on a manually mounted partition to reactivate the settings.  Having said this, you also need to use 'noauto' if you don't want fstab to try and automount the partition at boot.  I modified your post accordingly

Comment: I suppose then you've to remount the drive (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: You should unmount the drive first, modify the fstab data, and then remount and it should work with `exec` permissions.  However, you have a lot more options than are needed for *basic* mounting of an NTFS with exec permissions.  I will include my fstab I use for one of my executable NTFS flash drives that ends up mounted at `/media/ProgramUSB` as an example.  That is, when I get home.

Comment: Okay, so, on my system I ended up finding a different NTFS entry, but it works for my needs.  This mounts with the ability for the GUI to mount it to the specified path, alows read/write, has executable permissions, and mounting is NOT attempted at boot.  The problem  with this though is that the NTFS partition type *can't* be mounted via command line using `mount /path` in an installation, and needs sudo, something about NTFS user mount support not being built into the tools or something (12.04): `UUID=SOME-UUID  /media/16GBBitcoin          ntfs    noauto,user,rw,exec   0       0`

Comment: Awesome Brother @mohit It worked. Now I can run the eclipse without a single problem. Thanks to everyone. I'm really surprised finding that the linux community is so helpful i can't imagine. I also learned a lot of things from everyone who answered my qwestion.

Comment: IMO a better option is to mount the ntfs partition with the permissions option see http://askubuntu.com/questions/86959/any-way-of-maintaining-permissions-when-using-ntfs-mounted-drive-in-ubuntu