# apache forbidden to acces `index` file on ntfs partition

Tags: mount, permissions, apache2, 13.10, ntfs-3g

After Installing my apache, i edited the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file, and added in the bottom-line, the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /media/username/DATA/docs/pathtowebsite/website
 ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

The `DocumentRoot` points to a external NTFS partition!

But after adding the lines, and restarting the `apache2` service i get the following when ticking `localhost` in the Firefox adres-bar:

**Error**

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> ---
>
> Apache/2.4.6
>   (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I tried fiddling with the `fstab` per this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86959/any-way-of-maintaining-permissions-when-using-ntfs-mounted-drive-in-ubuntu), but same error, after restart.

I then installed [`ntfs-config`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ntfs-config/), checked the `enable write support for internal device` box, but same error after restart?

and `ntfs-config`, also edits the `fstab` file, so am not sure what to remove and what to keep?

```
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=3490454b-b5b0-4296-ae98-51ab08eecabc   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=506C44946C44772E   /media/SYSTEM   ntfs-3g defaults,locale=nl_NL.UTF-8 0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda3 :
UUID=01CCC676F2E07A60   /media/blade/DATA   ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=nl_NL.UTF-8    0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=9A3E8BF63E8BC9A9   /media/sda2 ntfs-3g defaults,locale=nl_NL.UTF-8 0   0
/dev/sda6   none    swap    sw  0   0

#UUID=01CCC676F2E07A60  /mnt/DATA   ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=nl_NL.UTF-8    0   0
#UUID=01CCC676F2E07A60  /mnt/DATA   ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions  0   0
```

I `gksu nautilus` to my external ntfs partition and tried to edit the permisions from my `website` folder, but, the `group` keeps jumping back to `root`. Also doesn't work via command-line.

**Question**: How can i edit my permissions on a NTFS drive, so that the `www-data` user can read my `index` file?

**Note**: Running Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Can you confirm if this is a simple permission issue by `sudo su <whatever-account-your-apache-runs-as>` (probably `www-data`) and then try to `cd` into `/media/blade/DATA` and see if you can open files.

Comment: @Oli, am currently at the office, but, when am home I'll give it a go. so, to be continued...

Comment: @Oli when i do `sudo su www-data`, i cant `cd` in to my external partition. I can `cd`to `/` but not `/media/blade`. when i cd in to my website folder, and then do `sudo su www-data` i can `rm` a `test.html`? soo this seems like a configuration issue? any idea where to conf this?

Comment: If you're using it mainly for just apache, just mount it with fuse as the apache-www user.  I use nginx, so I'll be of little help on the details.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Ubuntu 13.10, Apache 2.4 is installed which means that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445686/ubuntu-server-apache-2-4-6-client-denied-by-server-configuration-php-fpm) can be the problem - I had the same problem yesterday and changed the permissions of every directory up to DocumentRoot which did not help and then found the linked to post.

In the `<directory>` section (which you might have to add) just change `Allow from all` to `Require all granted`.

Comment: They already are at `Require all granted`. Am thinking that this is an `ntfs` issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried an experiment of mounting a ntfs with your parameters and `www-data` was also not able to cd to it. I then changed the mount point to `/mnt/Data` and was able to cd to it. After a bit more sniffing I came to the following conclusion, `/media/username` permission's for others is `none`, and by running `sudo chmod o+rX /media/username` to change it to `Access` enables www-data to cd to it - and possible the ability to access the data.

Comment: `sudo chmod o+rX /media/username` did the trick for me